# CakePHP 1.3 Auth component not hashing password on login

Tags: hash, authentication, cakephp-1.3

I know this has been asked several times, but many people are having problems with CakePHP 2.0, not 1.3. Plus, no one has provided the correct solution to this kind of problem.

Sign up works just fine. It hashes the password the way it's expected to do.
Typing passwords in the form does not let the user log in, whereas typing hashed passwords (same as in the db) does!

Isn't the Auth component supposed to hash the password after sending the data?

Here's the code (I know I should sanitize the inputs, I'll do that later)

UsersController

```
class UsersController extends AppController{

var $uses = array('Project','User','ProjectsUser');
var $helpers = array('Html');
var $components = array('RequestHandler','Auth');


function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('register');
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'projects', 'action' => 'dashboard');
}

function login() {

}

function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

function register(){
    if($this->RequestHandler->isPost()){
        if(!empty($this->data)){
            $email = $this->data['email'];
            $password = $this->Auth->password($this->data['password']);
            $first_name = $this->data['first_name'];
            $last_name = $this->data['last_name'];

            $data = array('email' => $email,'password'=>$password,'first_name' => $first_name,'last_name' => $last_name);

            $bool = true;
            $bool &= $this->User->save($data);

            if($bool){
                $this->setInitMsg('OK','Your account has been successfully created!');
                $this->redirect('/projects/dashboard');
            }else{
                $this->setInitMsg('ERROR', "Couldn't create an account");
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller{
    public $data;
    var $components = array('Session','Auth');

    public function beforefilter(){
        $this->data = $this->params['form'];
    }
}
```

Login view

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
                Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AuthComponent requires data to be sent this way

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
    (
        [username] => me@me.com
        [password] => 8ed3b7e8ced419a679a7df93eff22fae
    )
)
```

My code was missing the "User" key